# Finding a pole when the numerator is 0)

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

In a more informal way, is it right in saying that $\frac{sin(z)}{z^3}$ has a pole of order 2 at $z=0$ because it would be order 3 (because of the $z^3$) but the $sin(z)$ is also $0$ so we just take one away? Hope that makes sense :/

Thanks!

Comment: In general if $f,g$ are holomorphic and $f$ has a zero of order $m$ at $a$, $g$ has a zero of order $n$ at $a$ and $n>m$, then $f/g$ has a pole of order $n-m$ at $a$.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, $f(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z^3}$ has a pole of order two at $z=0$. Computing the Laurent series gives

$$f(z)= \frac{1}{z^2} - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{z^2}{5!} - \cdots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} z^{(2n+1)-3}}{(2n+1)!}.$$